# Find Days Home SQL Query

Tags: ms-access, join

I have a list of trips that people in my organization have taken. The goal is to calculate the time that an individual has been home between trips, looking at the past and the future on scheduled trips. The trips have not been entered in chronological order. I want to run a query on the table to fill the DaysHome for each trip.

```
Table: Trips
Name    DaysHome Departed      Returned
Evan             1/1/2011      2/1/2011
Joe              2/1/2011      5/1/2011
Evan             3/10/2011     4/10/2011
Evan             1/1/2010      6/1/2010
Joe              6/1/2011      7/1/2011
```

Ideally after the query the table would look like this, obviously the first trip in time entered for that person will be 0 because its the baseline trip.

```
Table: Trips
Name    DaysHome Departed      Returned
Evan    180      1/1/2011      2/1/2011
Joe     0        2/1/2011      5/1/2011
Evan    30       3/10/2011     4/10/2011
Evan    0        1/1/2010      6/1/2010
Joe     30       6/1/2011      7/1/2011
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know I need an Update query, I just don't know if I will need a Join or if I can just do a nested MAX search.

I am using Access 2007 for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version of the Trips table, I changed the field name "Name" to "Person" because Name is a reserved word.  I used DMax() to find the person's most recent return date prior to each departure.  Then DaysHome can be based on a DateDiff() expression between prev_return and Departed.

```
SELECT
    sub.Person,
    sub.Departed,
    sub.Returned,
    sub.prev_return,
    DateDiff('d',sub.prev_return,sub.Departed) AS DaysHome
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.Person,
            t.Departed,
            t.Returned,
            DMax("Returned", "Trips",
                "Person = '" & Person
                & "' AND Returned <= "
                & Format(Departed, "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#"))
                AS prev_return
        FROM Trips AS t
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.Person, sub.Departed;
```

This is the result set from that query.

```
Person Departed  Returned   prev_return DaysHome
Evan    1/1/2010  6/1/2010
Evan    1/1/2011  2/1/2011     6/1/2010      214
Evan   3/10/2011 4/10/2011     2/1/2011       37
Joe     2/1/2011  5/1/2011
Joe     6/1/2011  7/1/2011     5/1/2011       31
```

Notice my version has Null for DaysHome for what you called the "baseline trip".  But you said you want zero instead.  IMO Null is more meaningful here because you can't say how many days that person was home before his first Departure.  But if you really do want zero instead, use the Nz() function with that DateDiff() expression.

```
Nz(DateDiff('d',sub.prev_return,sub.Departed), 0) AS DaysHome
```

Also you said "I know I need an Update query".  Do not store DaysHome in the Trips table; don't store it anywhere.  Simply compute it when needed.  If you store it anywhere, your values could be out of sync when the Trips data is changed.

**Edit**: You're determined to store derived values in your Trips table.  Since you told us "I am using Access 2007 for this query", that means you can use a VBA user-defined function in your UPDATE query.  Using the GetDaysHome() function below, your UPDATE query could be as simple as this:

```
UPDATE Trips
SET Trips.DaysHome = GetDaysHome([Person],[Departed]);
```

Or, if you really want zero instead of Null as DaysHome for the "baseline trips", use the Nz() function:

```
UPDATE Trips
SET Trips.DaysHome = Nz(GetDaysHome([Person],[Departed]), 0);
```

Notice I re-named the Name field to Person because Name is a reserved word.

Although you could do the UPDATE using only plain SQL (without a UDF), this approach is just so much quicker for me to write, test, and describe.

```
Public Function GetDaysHome(ByVal pName As String, _
        ByVal pDeparture As Date) As Variant
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim varOut As Variant
    Dim varPrevReturned As Variant

    strCriteria = "Person = '" & pName & _
        "' AND Returned <= " & _
        Format(pDeparture, "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")
    varPrevReturned = DMax("Returned", "Trips", strCriteria)
    If Not IsNull(varPrevReturned) Then
        varOut = DateDiff("d", varPrevReturned, pDeparture)
    End If
    GetDaysHome = varOut
End Function
```

Comment: Is there any way to turn that into an UPDATE so the days home data is written back into the original table?

Comment: I know its not ideal (or good practice) but my office is using the table itself as the sole source of data. Meaning a query that kicks out the information will not be as useful, I'm trying your solution now, don't we need a max function somewhere to ensure it picks the most recent return?

Comment: I'm failing miserably at turning this into an update query. Thanks for your awesome help so far though

Comment: You could easily convert it into a make table query.  Although that would duplicate data from Trips, at least you would be guaranteed DaysHome is coherent with the Trips data snapshot.

Comment: I would like to update DaysHome from the answer above into the original table, any suggestions?